# Building static Qt 5.12 by mingw, can't found GLES2

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es-2.0, qmake, static-linking

I got following error when building static Qt.

> ....\include/QtGui/../../src/gui/opengl/qopengl.h:111:13: fatal
>   error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory  #   include

Here is how I configured:

```
cmd /c "configure.bat -static -release -platform win32-g++ -prefix $QtDir `
        -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -sql-odbc -sql-sqlite -no-openssl `
        -opensource -confirm-license `
        -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests"
```

Looks like new QML require `OpenGL ES2`. How to fix the error?

Config details:

```
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. no
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++1z
  Using gold linker ...................... no
  Using precompiled headers .............. yes
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    SSE .................................. SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2
    AVX .................................. AVX AVX2
    AVX512 ............................... F ER CD PF DQ BW VL IFMA VBMI
    Other x86 ............................ AES F16C RDRAND SHA
    Intrinsics without -mXXX option ...... yes
  Build parts ............................ libs examples tools
  App store compliance ................... no
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... no
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... no
  udev ................................... no
  Using system zlib ...................... yes
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... no
  iconv .................................. no
  ICU .................................... no
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  Using system PCRE2 ..................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... no
  IPv6 ifname ............................ no
  libproxy ............................... no
  OpenSSL ................................ no
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ no
  DTLS ................................... no
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ no
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. no
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... no
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ no
  EGL .................................... no
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    ANGLE ................................ no
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    Dynamic OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. no
  libinput ............................... no
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. no
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon-evdev ........................ no
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. no
  LinuxFB ................................ no
  VNC .................................... no
  Mir client ............................. no
  Windows:
    Direct 2D ............................ yes
    DirectWrite .......................... yes
    DirectWrite 2 ........................ yes
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows WindowsVista
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... no
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
Qt SerialBus:
  Socket CAN ............................. no
  Socket CAN FD .......................... no
Qt QML:
  QML network support .................... yes
  QML debugging and profiling support .... yes
  QML sequence object .................... yes
  QML list model ......................... yes
  QML XML http request ................... yes
  QML Locale ............................. yes
  QML delegate model ..................... yes
Qt Quick:
  Direct3D 12 ............................ no
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  TableView item ......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  Repeater item .......................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Scxml:
  ECMAScript data model for QtScxml ...... yes
Qt Gamepad:
  SDL2 ................................... no
Qt 3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
  Output Qt3D Job traces ................. no
  Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no
  Use SSE2 instructions .................. yes
  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no
  Aspects:
    Render aspect ........................ yes
    Input aspect ......................... yes
    Logic aspect ......................... yes
    Animation aspect ..................... yes
    Extras aspect ........................ yes
Qt 3D Renderers:
  OpenGL Renderer ........................ yes
Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:
  Autodesk FBX ........................... no
Qt Wayland Client ........................ no
Qt Wayland Compositor .................... no
Qt Bluetooth:
  BlueZ .................................. no
  BlueZ Low Energy ....................... no
  Linux Crypto API ....................... no
  WinRT Bluetooth API (desktop & UWP) .... no
Qt Sensors:
  sensorfw ............................... no
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Default Fusion Imagine Material Universal
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
Qt Positioning:
  Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no
  WinRT Geolocation API .................. no
Qt Location:
  Qt.labs.location experimental QML plugin . yes
  Geoservice plugins:
    OpenStreetMap ........................ yes
    HERE ................................. yes
    Esri ................................. yes
    Mapbox ............................... yes
    MapboxGL ............................. yes
    Itemsoverlay ......................... yes
QtXmlPatterns:
  XML schema support ..................... yes
Qt Multimedia:
  ALSA ................................... no
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... no
  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ no
  OpenAL ................................. no
  PulseAudio ............................. no
  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
  Windows Audio Services ................. no
  DirectShow ............................. yes
  Windows Media Foundation ............... no
  Media player backend ................... DirectShow
Qt WebEngine:
  Embedded build ......................... no
  Pepper Plugins ......................... yes
  Printing and PDF ....................... yes
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... no
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. yes
  Use System Ninja ....................... no
  Geolocation ............................ yes
  WebChannel support ..................... yes
  Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes
  Kerberos Authentication ................ yes
```

**Update:**

I success compiled `-opengl desktop` by installing `DirectX SDK`, but the static program which contains QML Camera display nothing.